# Using ::class dynamically

Tags: php

I want to create a helper method for my app where I pass a class name as a string. The method should then resolve the string into a fully qualified class name. So with namespace.

This is what I want to do. However, my IDE (PHPStorm) says: `"is only allowed on objects"`

```php
public function(string $className)
{
    return $className::class;
}
```

**Question:** What do I have to change to make this dynamic?

Comment: If the class is only from a specific namespace, then add this in as a fixed string.  If this is any class from any namespace then you will have to find it by looking through the namespaces for a class called that (AFAIK).

Comment: Isn't `$className` already the class name? Where does this function live?

Comment: That's a good hint from both of you @NigelRen and @AlexHowansky. The classes we are talking about all have the same namespace. So I can do this with a fixed namespace as string. Then I would only have to check if the class really exists. I would do that with `class_exists`. right?

Comment: Yes, it also is a good way of making it secure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the class is always in a specific namespace, then you can hard code it and also check if the class exists.  You can handle the error as you need to, this just throws an exception.

Having the classes in a specific namespace also allows you to limit the possible classes it uses and it also can help developers as they can see where these classes are defined.

```
public function className(string $className)
{
    $fullName = '\YourNameSpace\\' . $className;
    if (class_exists($fullName) === false) {
        throw new Exception('Class not found');
    }

    return $fullName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nigel! That's how I'm going to do it! You still have a nice day!

Comment: `if (class_exists($fullName)) {...}` is even sufficient.

Comment: You could also just use the `__NAMESPACE__`  constant instead of hard-coding it to make this more portable.

Comment: @MarkusAO, thats assuming it's the current namespace.

Comment: @NigelRen oh right. Then, if the function is hardwired to a specific non-current namespace, OP should probably call it `someNameSpaceClassName` or some such, to accommodate future functions for similar lookups in other namespaces.